# Linux Mint good fps but high ping while gaming

Tags: networking, linux-mint, gaming

I've installed rocket league (in epic games store) after installing lutris and wine in Linux Mint.
However, when I play an online match, my ping goes high and I get horrible packet loss but the frames aren't low.

So this seems to be a network issue yet my internet connection is stable.

I tried updating my network driver with this command :

```
inxi -Fxz
```

After pasting the output of that command, the terminal gave me an error (command inxi not found)
So then I tried to install it using :

```
sudo apt install inxi
```

I did the same process then but nothing has changed

Comment: Rocket League is known for the bad servers. It's mostly their issue, but could be your ISP too. My ISP is really bad when multiple people are online in the evenings. I can't play any matches without crazy rubber banding, packet loss, etc. "Good" ping for me connecting to US-East or US-West is anywhere between 50-90ms ping. Going over 100 is where the lag starts to occur. Some servers I have no issue, others are terrible.

Comment: Does the same happen in other online multiplayer game or is it just this one?

Comment: @DrZoo I don't think the issue is from their servers, because I had played it on Windows before and on the same pc and everything was OK

Comment: @Mokubai I don't know as I only play that game, but I think that this issue isn't only happening in rocket league